# Malloc a String in the Struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, char, malloc

The struct looks like this.

```c
struct Tree {
    int operation;
    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;
    char *value;
};
```

And next, I tried to create a tree with this function:

```c
struct Tree *new_node(int operation_new, struct Tree *left_new, struct Tree *right_new, char new_value[MAX_LENG]) {
    struct Tree *n;

    n = (struct Tree *)malloc (sizeof(struct Tree));

    if (n == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to Malloc New Structure Tree");
        exit(1);
    }
        
    n->operation = operation_new;
    n->left = left_new;
    n->right = right_new;

    // n->value = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(new_value) + 1)); // -------- ( 1 )
    n->value = new_value;
    return n;
}
```

So, I created a tree and printed it. Thus, when printing the tree, the **operation**, that is, the **integer** was printed correctly. But the **value** is not printed correctly. That is, only the value entered at the end of the tree (`node`) is printed everywhere. Value is a **String** (`char *`). So I googled about this problem. And I found this answer.

> **Malloc** char* to store it in **struct**

So I tried different ways to malloc this. Below are some Examples.

```c
// This gave me a Segmentation Fault
n->value = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(new_value) + 1));
strcpy(n->value, new_value);

// This gave me a Segmentation Fault
n->value = malloc(sizeof(strlen(new_value) + 1));
strcpy(n->value, new_value);
```

None of this gave an accurate result ! Can you tell me how to **malloc** a string in a struct correctly?

Comment: N->value=strdup(new_value)

Comment: And to explain: `sizeof` gives the storage size of the variable or value. You’re giving it the return value of `strlen` which is usually 4 or 8 bytes. So it will return 4 or 8 and you’ll allocate 5 or 9 bytes. Just use `strlen` directly as mentioned, or the other mentioned way `strdup` which is meant for creating a copy of a C string including allocating memory.

Comment: @user3121023 Sorry :/ Your code gave segmentation fault

Comment: @pm100 also Sorry :/ Your code gave segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allocate a copy of the string, use `strlen(new_value) + 1` as the size passed to `malloc`, passing `sizeof(strlen(new_value) + 1)` is incorrect and evaluates to `sizeof(size_t)` which is constant (typically 4 or 8 depending on the platform). The code is:

```
n->value = malloc(strlen(new_value) + 1);
if (n->value != NULL) {
    strcpy(n->value, new_value);
}
```

Note this simpler way to allocate a copy of the string in a single call:

```
n->value = strdup(new_value);
```

Comment: While [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) is usually available, it is not (yet) standard C but rather a POSIX extension.  The distinction only matters if you use compiler options that preclude the declaration of functions not in Standard C (such as GCC's `-std=c11` option).  It is simplest to use `-std=gnu11` instead; failing that, activate POSIX before including the first system header with `#define _XOPEN_C_SOURCE 700`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. But that code gave segmentation fault :(

Comment: Sorry :) Your answer is correct. I forgot something in my Code. Thank you Very Much !